# Excel datetime surface chart

Tags: excel, datetime, surface

Is it possible to build a surface chart in Excel with dates in the X-axis, time in the Y-axis and the number of observations in the Z-axis?

For the Y-axis I imagine 24 buckets, one for each hour of the day.

The Z-axis would count the number of observations in each hour period.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't. What have you tried?

Comment: Selecting the columns where my data is, Insert > Charts > Surface. Didn't work. I have dates in one column and time in another.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71561728/edit) to show us what your data look like dates should be in a column, time in a row, or the other way around. A quick search reveals tons of tutorials on creating this kind of chart

Comment: Just realized Excel needs the data to be in a table format, where the column and row labels are the dates and hours. The body of that table must count each observation. By selecting the table and going to Charts > Surface, the chart will be generated.